# Postfix - Discarding EHLO Keywords Duplicate Log Entries

Tags: postfix, smtpd

Ubuntu 20.04
Postfix 3.4

For each message received by my Postfix I see the following two entries:

```
Mar  8 16:34:42 mail postfix/smtpd[863775]: discarding EHLO keywords: ETRN DSN
Mar  8 16:34:42 mail postfix/smtpd[863775]: discarding EHLO keywords: ETRN DSN
```

My configuration...

```
me@mail:/etc/postfix$ postconf -n |grep smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = ETRN, DSN
```

`smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords` does not exist in master.cf, but even if it did that overrides - not additive - main.cf, correct?

How can I stop this behavior or is it normal (albeit odd)?

Thanks.

Comment: I could imagine setups where specifying it once, globally, applies to two separate `smtpd` services. Adding `-o syslog_name=example` below additional `smtpd` lines in `master.cf` would clarify such situations.

Comment: I think I see where you're going with that and made your suggested edit.  The two entries are now `...mail example/smtpd...` instead of how I previously noted.  If your logic played out I think we should have seen an entry with the previous label (`postfix/smtpd`) as well as an entry with `example/smtpd`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Its harmless - actually, the norm**, in all but rare special cases: Almost all clients will send `EHLO` once to coax the server into revealing that yes, of course, it will accept the `STARTTLS` workaround to upgrade the existing connection to a secure channel. And then they will have to send `EHLO` again because the server is not allowed to reuse anything received from the preceding insecure channel:

> Upon completion of the TLS handshake, the SMTP protocol is reset to
> the initial state (the state in SMTP after a server issues a 220
> service ready greeting).

(Well, at least its [supposed to](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207.html#section-4.2). There were a few very unfortunate bugs around this, allowing malicious third-parties insert commands in an believed-to-be secure session.)

It is even possible that a misconfigured client send EHLO more often than twice, not necessarily hampering actual deliveries. I have seen that happen with broken intercepting ([MitM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) firewalls.

---

You can make the fact that the two messages refer to mostly-separate SMTP protocol sessions *more visible* in your log by increasing your `smtpd_tls_loglevel` from its zero default. I strongly recommend to not exceed smtpd_tls_loglevel=2, higher values produce excessive logs and reveal connection details best *not* persisted.

You could make the fact that postfix silently disregarded some keywords more silent by adding the special `silent-discard` to your `smtpd_discard_*_keywords` parameter. I strongly recommend to not do that, and instead add comment and/or log parser configuration help future admins (or other readers of that log message) understand your justification for configuring your server with such non-standard behaviour.

Comment: That is exactly it.  Once TLS loglevel was bumped up I see a number of TLS log entries in between the two entries indicating keyword discard.  The reset after `STARTTLS` escaped my mind.  This all makes sense now.  Thanks.